# Can I always use Gaussian elimination to prove a matrix has no real eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

If a matrix $M$ has no real eigenvalues, and if I don't know how to prove that its characteristic polynomial has no real roots, can I always prove it using Gaussian elimination on $M-xI$ and succeeding in reaching a complete row echelon form with diagonal entries either of degree 0 or 2 that have no roots ?

--------Edit following one of the answers :

Say I want to prove that a real matrix $M$ has no real eigenvalues. Suppose its characteristic polynomial $P$ isn't easy to split into quadratic polynomials. If I could use Gaussian elimination on $M-xI$ to make it upper triangular in such a way that half of its diagonal entries are nonzero constants and the other half are rootless quadratic polynomials, the question would be resolved. My question is : can this always be done ?

(If so, does that mean that for any polynomial $P$ with no real roots, applying this to method to $C(P)-xI$, where $C(p)$ denotes the companion matrix of $P$, provides a method for factorising $P$ into quadratics ?)

Comment: How will that prove that $M$ has no eigenvalues? For instance, the zero matrix has eigenvalue $0$; can you bring $-xI$ to complete row echelong form?

Comment: What do you mean with "has not eigenvalues"?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, what I mean is not that the simple fact of having a row echelon form proves that the matrix has no eigenvalues, rather, if a matrix has no eigenvalues, can I always reach an upper triangular matrix with only nonzero values and polynomials with clearly no roots ? I'll edit

Comment: Regarding your edit: I have no idea what you mean by your last sentence.  That being said, you can always put $M - xI$ into [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form#Similarity).  The notion of [Frobenius normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) is related; perhaps this is what you had in mind with companion matrices.

Comment: I've reformulated my last sentence to try and make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "no eigenvalues", I assume you mean "no real eigenvalues".  If that's what you mean, then yes that works.  For instance, the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
has no real eigenvalues.  To verify that, we can compute $M - x I$ and row-reduce:
$$
M - x I = \pmatrix{-x & -1\\1&-x} \leadsto
\pmatrix{1&-x\\-x & -1} \leadsto
\pmatrix{1&-x\\0&-x^2-1}.
$$
Now, note that $-x^2 - 1$ is never zero (for real values $x$).  So, we can divide the bottom row by $-x^2 - 1$.  So, we have row-reduced $M - xI$ to 
$$
M - x I \leadsto \pmatrix{1&-x\\0&1} \leadsto \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.
$$
So for any real $x$, $M - xI$ can be row-reduced to the identity matrix.  So for any real $x$, $M - xI$ is invertible, which is to say that $x$ is not an eigenvalue of $M$.

Thus, $M$ indeed has no real eigenvalues.

---

Keep in mind that along this process, we did ultimately end up with an entry equal to $-(x^2 + 1)$; $x^2 + 1$ is in fact the characteristic polynomial of $M$.  So a long story short: if you're computing (or checking for the existence of) eigenvalues by hand, calculating $\det(M - xI)$ in some way is still the way to go.